# How to solve this security puzzle in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command-line

As part of practicing with linux tools I've been trying random "bash challenges" and am stuck with one. I'm in a restricted bash shell where I can't `cd`, and I can't run commands with forward slashes in them. Output redirection is unvailable as well. The PATH environment variable is also set to point to a very limited subset of tools. Namely:

```
awk,cmp,cut,egrep,find,grep,gzip,hostname,less,lsof,netstat,nm,ps,sed,ssh-agent,
sum,tar,uname,vi,whoami,xz,zcat,cat,column,diff,fgrep,gdb,gzcat,head,
ifconfig,ls,mv,nl,ping,sort,strings,tail,top,uniq,xargs,xzcat
```

Now, using `awk` I am able to access an unrestricted shell - and the puzzle question is: "If you have a limited amount of time before `awk` is removed from the list of usable commands - is there a way to secure yourself a way of reaching unrestricted shell in the future? The home directory under this user is not writable.

Under the awk unrestricted shell I tried making a copy of `/bin/sh` into some other location `/tmp/writable`...but that doesn't work because I can't later `cd` into /tmp/writable`and i can't run`/tmp/writable/sh` because it contains forward slashes. I also can't just make a soft link, for the same reason. Assuming I can't leave something permanent in the login scripts (easily detected), is there any other approach to this?

Comment: "If you have a limited amount of time before" - well, you don't know how fast the system is, so for me, this is the same thing as saying you have an unlimited amount of time...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath "limited" means you don't know when it will be removed, but it's not permanent. The problem is to set do something before it's removed that will allow you to get a shell after it's removed.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you find that?

Answer (score 2):

Since `chsh` is setuid root, you can modify your login shell to be unrestricted using `awk` (I presume you can execute it, since you can execute the unrestricted shell). Then, the next time you login, you will not have a restricted shell anymore.

Otherwise, as Brian Campbell points out, there are other ways to gain access to an unrestricted shell besides `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have GDB available, you can just call one of the [`exec`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execl.3.html) functions from there to get an unrestricted shell

```
$ gdb cat
(gdb) run
^C
(gdb) call execl("/bin/sh", 0);
$
```

And now you're in an unrestricted shell.

Comment: Or `find . -maxdepth 0 -exec /bin/sh \;`